# How to animate HubSection when visibility changed in WinRT Hub Control

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a HubSection that is dynamically shown/hidden using Visibility Collapsed/Visible during runtime.  I would like to animate the HubSection by having it expand and shrink instead of just instantly showing or hiding it.

Animations in WinRT tend to be a science, and I haven't found a good method yet.

If someone could help with a code snippet I would appreciate it.  I would prefer to keep it to XAML if possible, rather than putting the animation in a code-behind.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sure, among other things I have tried attaching an event trigger, but there doesn't seem to be a trigger for visibility.

Comment: I think that you will have to write a behavior to check the visibility of the hub section. And then add the ControlStoryboard action to it that is allready provided. [This is a good link](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/behaviors-in-windows-8-1-store-apps/)

Comment: Thanks for the link Corcus.  It may come down to something like that, but I was hoping there was a somewhat elegant XAML solution to it.  I feel like I've been here before, trying to animate based on visibility, and I ran into similar problems before.

Comment: I think if you have had this problem before then a behavior is what you need since it is reusable. I don't have one for visibility myself or I would have posted it. If I get the time I will make one though.

Comment: Wow, if you do get the time I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the visibiity of the hubsection is controlled by a boolean property of a viewmodel, bound through a converter then the solution is simpler than I thought. Even if this is not the case I'm sure you can modify the solution below easily.

You will need to reference the Behaviors SDK for this to work. You can do that either by going to References>Add Reference>Windows 8.1>Extensions>Behaviors SDK or by opening your project in blend and dragging a DataTriggerBehavior on yor hubsection.

Necessary xmlns declarations

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"

<Page.Resources>
    <Converters:BoolToVisConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="hubSection">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="400"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Hub Header="Hub">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior/>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <HubSection Header="HubSection 0">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection x:Name="hubSection" Header="HubSection 1" Visibility="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" Width="400" Background="#FFB02626">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
    <ToggleSwitch Header="ToggleSwitch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="824,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsOn="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The xaml defines a hub with 2 hubsections a toggleswitch to manipulate the boolean property in the viewmodel and a storyboard to animate the second hubsection.

The trick is to use a DataTriggerBehavior instead of an EventTriggerBehavior.

You can even bind directly to the visibility property of the hubsection for the DataTriggerBevavior if you want.

Comment: Corcus, I am trying to implement this and I'm running into some errors.  Among other things, the worst-sounding error that I'm encountering in my build is "DataTriggerBehavior is not supported in a Windows App project."  Is this a WPF solution, or can it be used in WinRT?

Comment: No it is for a windows 8.1 store application. You need to reference the Behaviors SDK. Go to References>Add Reference>Windows8.1>Extensions>Behaviors SDK and add it to your project. Or open your project in blend and drag a DataTriggerBehavior on your hubsection, this will automatically include all you need.

Comment: Editing in Blend as you suggested did the trick.  I did some various tweaks on the animations and added an "out" animation, and things are looking good now.  One thing I had to do was to remove the visibility binding, because it does not allow an "out" transition (because it immediately sets visibility to collapsed).  Setting width to 0 at the end of the animation accomplishes the same thing.  Thanks so much for the awesome assistance!